# How can we enhance our serach performance in a large application that works with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, performance, nhibernate, search

How can we enhance our `serach performance` in a large application that works with `NHibernate`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a rather general question. It always depends on what you search in what data structure.

So I can only give you general advises:

- Use indexes
- optimize the data structure, for instance by avoiding joins paths and avoid conditions
- optimize HQL
- use query batches
- use `select new`
- in very special cases, use native sql or views

Answer (score 0):

What about using Full-Text Search or [Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/)?